# Can't register user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have model User and two controllers for manage users:

1. Devise (without changes) - user can register and log in through Devise. Authorization works without problems,but registration does not work. Also the user cannot delete his account.
2. admin_users controller - user management through the admin panel. Here everything works flawlessly, except for deleting the user.

Devise controller is original
admin_users_controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin_application"

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user.id).order("id ASC")
    #authorize @users
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #authorize @user
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    #authorize @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    #authorize @user
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created User."
      redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #authorize @user
    params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?

    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
      redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to admin_users_path
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :role_id, :birth_date, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

ApplicationController
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include Pundit # Pundit authorisation

```
  add_flash_types :success, :danger, :info

  before_action :authenticate_user! # All users must be logged in redirect to lgin page

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:avatar])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:avatar, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :username, :birth_date])
    end
end
```

Links to delete in views

```
= link_to "Delete", user_path(current_user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-danger"
```

and

```
= link_to "Delete", admin_user_path(@user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-danger"
```

Console log when Devise registration:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-01-25 14:02:21 +0300
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test5@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (1.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test5@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.haml
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.haml (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 35)
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.haml (Duration: 2.0ms | Allocations: 428)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 16.8ms | Allocations: 1232)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (Duration: 3.3ms | Allocations: 155)
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.haml (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 18)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.haml (Duration: 28.4ms | Allocations: 4102)
Completed 200 OK in 676ms (Views: 29.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms | Allocations: 8572)
```

And when ttry to delete account (GET method???):

```
Started GET "/users/0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-01-25 14:57:01 +0300
Processing by DashboardController#user as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"0"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.haml
  Rendering dashboard/user.html.haml within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 0], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "avatar"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/application_helper.rb:12:in `avatar'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/application_helper.rb:13:in `avatar'
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/dashboard/user.html.haml:14
  Rendered dashboard/user.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 808.7ms | Allocations: 22183)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 289)
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.haml (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 18)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.haml (Duration: 1072.4ms | Allocations: 42813)
Completed 200 OK in 1481ms (Views: 1073.2ms | ActiveRecord: 35.9ms | Allocations: 54136)
```

Can enybody help me? Thanks

Comment: The user you are trying to create already exists that is why it is not allowing you to create the user again. For the delete request, it is being sent as GET instead of DELETE that is why it is not reaching to destroy action.

Comment: No, I have no that user in database. and i know about GET but I cant resolve why. I call method DELETE in my link. So...